# Error while updating a row in my SQL which has a set trigger

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

In the error console it displays :

Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'warriors' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

This is my table :

[image: This is the Table in which the trigger is set]

This is the trigger creation statement:

```
create trigger power_update
after update on   warriors 
 for each row update warriors 
set power = (practise_hours * 100);
```

This is the statement to update the table

```
update warriors set practise_hours = 80 where id = 9;
```

Comment: Your update trigger updates the same table. This would lead to an infinite loop, in which the trigger would cause itself to fire. Hence it gets rejected.

Comment: Is there any reason why power cannot be a computed column?

Answer (score 1):

This should Work Fine in MySQL

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER update_power BEFORE UPDATE ON warriors
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.powers = NEW.practice_hours * 100;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

You have to use the `NEW` keyword to reference the updated values combined with a `BEFORE` trigger since the `AFTER` cannot modify the `NEW` row values.

`DELIMITER` allows us to change the default delimiter `;`

However, a [Generated/Computed Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) might be a better solution.